# How can I get backtrace of this Perl Project? (Segmentation Fault)

Tags: postgresql, gdb

I test now an web application at my job. I use Debian. I don't know what kind of project is, just know that is built in **Perl** and uses **PostgreSQL**. The project where Back-End is built, uses **CARTON**, a Perl module dependency manager (aka Bundler for Perl) http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Carton-v1.0.12/lib/Carton.pm. To run the Back-End I have to start PostgreSQL `sudo su postgres` and then execute command `carton exec foo` and Back-End start to work. But today, after some updates and upgrades, I executed it and got this error message `Segmentation fault`. I found that to check what was going on I had to get a backtrace so I found and read this article:

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Linux/BSD

but still don't understand how to run the project with GDB.

Thanks

Comment: I would appreciate some feedback before punish me with a -1. That would be nice

Comment: What is `carton exec foo`?  That is not a valid command in `PostgreSQL` that I know of.  Also, what does "start in gdb mode" mean?  That is not a terminology used in either of the references you cite.  Since the references are complex and with many different options, we don't know what exactly it is you did unless you describe in the same words the references use.

Comment: Thanks for Feedback! Carton is a Perl module dependency manager [link](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Carton-v1.0.12/lib/Carton.pm) and to run this back-end (Do I say it right?) my company showed my that command. When I said "gdb mode" I meant start using gdb to debug. I'm going to edit the question. Thanks a lot

Comment: As far as I can tell, `carton` is a perl script - its first line is `#!perl` - which can load and run perl scripts. So try running `gdb perl`, and then at the (gdb) prompt, type `run -f carton exec foo`.

Comment: Didn't work neither. Is GDB for me the best option for doing that? Maybe I should use another procedure to do this.

Comment: I just realized - you either need to be in the directory that contains the carton script or you need to give perl (using gdb's `run` command) the full pathname of the carton script instead of just `run  carton`. And don't use `-f` - I was wrong about what perl does with that option. If you get any error messages, can you paste them here?

Answer (score 0):

> but still didn't find out how to get a backtrace. Once I start in gdb mode, I don't know what to type to run the back-end in gdb mode.

It's hard to answer your question because it's not clear exactly where you are getting stuck.

Use the first link you provided, to attach GDB to the running back end:

```
sudo gdb -p pid
(gdb) continue
```

Now execute whatever command causes your backend to crash. Once you do, GDB will stop and print something like:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004004c0 in foo (p=0x0) at t.c:1
(gdb)
```

*Now* you are ready to obtain the crash stack trace, by using `where` GDB command.

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x00000000004004c0 in foo (p=0x0) at t.c:1
#1  0x00000000004004dc in bar (p=0x0) at t.c:2
#2  0x00000000004004ec in main () at t.c:4
```

You will likely not get file/line info and parameter values (you'll need to install debuginfo packages described in your second link for that), but you should get function names, which may be sufficient to find the relevant bug.

Comment: How can I know **pid** if it's not running?

Comment: If to run Back-End I have to execute `carton exec foo`, I execute first `gdb foo` and then GDB starts and print this: **"foo":not in executable format: File format not recognized**. So whatever I try to execute in GDB I get an error message.